# Postfix as mail relay for web servers?

Tags: postfix, email, linux-networking

I want to set up Postfix to relay mail from a group of webservers. I would like to limit senders by IP so I can restrict the box to only my webservers, so I don't have an open relay and don't have to worry about authentication. So, what I guess I need is to limit inbound access but allow mail to be sent to any outbound address. I've looked through the docs and don't even know where to start, so any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the accepted answer to [Setting up a postfix email server](https://serverfault.com/questions/5671/setting-up-a-postfix-email-server). Where the mynetworks in that example is set to 127.0.0.1/32 you will want to list the ips of your other servers as well. So something like:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1/32, 10.0.1.1/32, 192.168.132.1.1/32
```

Comment: thanks very much! that link and your suggestion did the trick.